# Create a multiple self referencing class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How can i get EF to build up the DB from following class the right way? Is there any way to archive this with DataAnnotation-Attributes only?

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public long ItemId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Item> PrevItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> NextItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following was my solution:

1. Create a configuration class:

   ```
   public ItemConfiguration()
   {
       this.HasMany(x => x.NextItems)
          .WithMany(x => x.PrevItems)
          .Map(x => x.ToTable("RelatedItems"));
   }
   ```
2. Override OnModelCreating in DbContext

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ItemConfiguration());
   }
   ```

I am not sure if that is 100% correct, but it seems to work.

If someone knows how to archive this with DataAnnotation-Attributes only, i would be happy to know!